# How do I launch a remote kernel on one Win 10 system from another Win 10 sys?

Tags: kernel, remote-access

I have two win 10 computers and I have enabled the built-in windows 10 OpenSSH Client and OpenSSH serve in both of them. I can use one of the computers to run programs on another computer. I have also set up the remote kernel through "kernel configuration options" and I can use the remote kernel from the local front-end.

Now I am trying to do parallel computing. I need to launch a remote kernel. According to the help documentation, I tried the command like this：

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]
LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine[host,
  "ssh username@host \"D:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\11.3\\MathKernel -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2`\"", 1]]
```

When I run this command a blank CMD window was popped up. I waited for a while and nothing happened (strictly speaking a Wolfram kernel process was in high CPU usage). So I closed the CMD window, and some error messages appeared:

> LaunchRemote::time: Operation Run timed out after 15.` seconds.
>
> LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject[62800@192.168.132.253, 62801@192.168.132.253, 225, 10] in LinkConnectedQ[LinkObject[62800@192.168.132.253, 62801@192.168.132.253, 225, 10]] has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed.

I googled for a long time and didn't find a solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found a way to launch remote kernal in win10 like this:

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]
LaunchKernels[
 RemoteMachine["192.168.132.233", 
  "bash -c \"ssh -f Administrator@`1` E:/M/math -wstp -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit\"", 1]]
```

Those parameters, "192.168.132.233","Administrator" and "E:/M/math", need to be replaced.

To use this code one need to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux(I use this [Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)), and sets the ssh login without password from the subsystem to remote PC.

To launch n kernels one can use "Do[..,n]" to repeat the code above.

Why one cannot launch remote kernels by directly using CMD command shell seems that CMD cannot run background nor generate a return. This may cause the launch time out.

Comment: Good luck with connection resumability and dynamics!